# Find a $f$ function such that$f'(x)\geq 0$ but not continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I just started reading continuity, differentiability etc. So I was thinking of an example of following type:

> Let $f: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing continuous function and differentiable on $(a,b)$ or simply $f'(x)\geq 0$ for $x\in (a,b)$.
>
> can we find such function for which $f'(x)$ is not continuous?

I could not find any, whatever function I take $f'(x)$ is becoming continuous. Is there such function even exists!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every $x\in (-1,1).$ Define,
$$ f(x) = 100x+ x^2\sin\frac{1}{x} \qquad\text{with $f(0)=0$}$$
which is differentiable and 
$$ f'(x) =  100+ 2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}  \qquad\text{with $f'(0)=100$}$$
$f'$ is not continuous a $x=0$ and you might choose the interval $[a,b]$ around $x=0$ as it suite to you. Indeed

$$ f'(x)=100+2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x} \ge 100+ 2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-1$$

Since $|\sin a| \le |a|$ and $-1\le-\cos a\le 1$ then $|2x\sin\frac{1}{x}|\le 2$ i.e $$2x\sin\frac{1}{x}\ge -2 $$

therefore

$$ f'(x)=100+2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x} \ge 100-2-1= 97>0$$ for every $x\in \mathbb R$. so $f $ is increasing and  $f'$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Defined on what closed interval?

Comment: but the function is increasing in near $0$

Comment: Monotone?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: you can choose your interval from the left of o or from the right both will give monotonicity for sure.

Comment: I don't understand, is this function monotonically increasing in $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$, $\epsilon>0$

Comment: $f'(x)<0$ for some $x$ on $(0,1)$, $(-1,0)$, and $(-1,1)/\{0\}$, so it is not monotonically increasing on just any interval around $0$ or beside $0$.

Comment: @user467365 $h(x)=3x-f(x)$ should work ($f$ as above).

Comment: Thanks @DavidMitra good proposal.

Comment: @user467365 I fixed your doubt now take $(1,1)$ check it again.

Comment: checked and thanks @GuyFabrice

Comment: I never saw this example with $100x$. Anything like $kx$ with $k>1$ would have worked. But perhaps keeping it $100x$ makes $f'(x) >0$ as blatantly obvious. +1

Comment: Hahahaha it just that user467365 was too skeptical about the first argument in fact 3x is enough to reach the answer. but your right @paramanand Singh.