# $f>0$, $f'\geq 0$ but not continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This question is continuation of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396826/fx-geq-0-but-not-continuous) question. (And last of this type)

> Let $f: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $f(x)$ is monotonically non-decreasing **positive** continuous function and differentiable on $(a,b)$ or simply $f'(x)\geq 0$ for $x\in (a,b)$.
>
> can we find such function for which $f'(x)$ is not continuous?

I could not find any,obviously. Is there such function even exists!

Comment: The positivity assumption on $f$ is useless. $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ by continuity, so if you find a counterexample $f$ which is not positive, you can make it so by adding a constant, namely $\lVert f\rVert_\infty+1$.

Comment: BTW, Monotonously increasing and $f'\ge 0$, aren't the same thing. $f'\ge 0$ implies non-decreasing function.

Comment: @JaideepKhare are you saying I should write Monotonously non-decreasing?

Comment: @user467365 exactly, if $f'\ge 0$ is what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x\in(-1,1)$
$$ f(x) =100000+ 100x+ x^2\sin\frac{1}{x} \qquad\text{with $f(0)=100000$}$$
which is differentiable,  and 
$$ f'(x) =  100+ 2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}  \qquad\text{with $f'(0)=100$}$$
$f'$ is not continuous a $x=0$ and you might choose the interval $[a,b]$ around $x=0$ as it suite to you. Indeed

$$ f'(x)=100+2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x} \ge 100+ 2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-1$$

Since $|\sin a| \le |a|$ and $-1\le-\cos a\le 1$ then $|2x\sin\frac{1}{x}|\le 2$ i.e $$2x\sin\frac{1}{x}\ge -2 $$

therefore

$$ f'(x)=100+2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x} \ge 100-2-1= 97>0$$ for every $x\in \mathbb R$. so $f $ is increasing and  $f'$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Also $|x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}|\le 1$ for all $x\in (-1,1)$ so that 
$$f(x) =100000+ 100x+ x^2\sin\frac{1}{x} > 100000-100 -1 >0$$ for every $x\in (-1,1).$

Comment: thanks again,...

Comment: I don't want to be overly critical, but what is the point of reproducing pretty much exactly the answer to the previous question with **all** the analysis, while it suffices to explain "take the same function and add a constant, since all that was missing was $f>0$"?

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(x)=1+3x+x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$ if $x\in(0,1]$ and $f(0)=1$. It satisfies your conditions, but $f'$ is discountinuous at $0$.

Comment: do we have $f'\ge 0$?

Comment: @GuyFabrice Not necessarily. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I think $3x$ is more secure.

Comment: @GuyFabrice Right you are! Of I course, I could also put an interval shorter than $(0,1]$, but I will follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Take the function $f$ from the question you link. It is already a monotonically increasing continuous function and differentiable on $[a,b]$, yet $f'$ is not continuous. It is only missing positivity.

Make it positive by adding $\lVert f\rVert_\infty+1$ (possible since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, so bounded). This does not change the derivative.

You then have an answer to your new question.